# How many times a product have been bought by customer in last one year

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce how to check how many times a product has been bought by a customer when the product price is 0 for last one year. To achieve this I try the bellow code and get the answer separately , the result is not shorting by product name or ID. Please help how can i short them.

**Here is the code**

```
//Check if bought it in last one year and the number of quantity
function customer_bought_qty(){

    //get the value of targeted product
    $_options = get_option( 'license_page_option_name' );
    $ex_product_ids = $_options['ex_product_ids_warranty']; 
    $target_products = explode(",",$ex_product_ids); //array(18,63,85)


    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with status "completed"
        'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
                    'after' => '1 year ago',
                )
            )
        ) );

   // Going through each orders for current customer 
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
        $order_id = $order->id;
        $items = $order->get_items();
        $subtotal = $order->get_subtotal(); //to check how many free item bought

    //Loop trough the order items and see if it is a product we need to cehck
        foreach($items as $item) {          
            if($subtotal== 0 && in_array($item['product_id'], $target_products)) {  
                $_product_id = $item['product_id'];
                $_product_qty = $item['qty'];
                if(isset ($_product_id)){
                    echo '('. get_the_title($_product_id). ')# You bought '.$_product_qty.' Times<br>';
                }
            }   
        }
    }

}
```

**The Output looks**

```
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
```

**But I need the result should be look like**

```
(Product 2)# You bought 4 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 4 Times
```

Comment: I'm not so familiar with wordpress | woocommerce but wouldn't it be easier to do using sql and `GROUP BY` product ?

Comment: @VitaliiStrimbanu may be possible but they not in same table and difficult to understand how to get

Answer (score 0):

to accomplish that you need a new array to store the actual quantity for each product

```
$quantity_per_product = array();
```

and when you *foreach* items you update this array

```
if(array_key_exists($_product_id, $quantity_per_product)){
   $quantity_per_product[$_product_id] += $item['qty']
}
else{
   $quantity_per_product[$_product_id] = $item['qty']
}
```

so your actual code should look something like:

```
$quantity_per_product = array();

//Loop trough the order items and see if it is a product we need to cehck
foreach($items as $item) {          
    if($subtotal== 0 && in_array($item['product_id'], $target_products))   {  
         $_product_id = $item['product_id'];
         if(isset ($_product_id)){
              if(array_key_exists($_product_id, $quantity_per_product))
              {
                  $quantity_per_product[$_product_id] += $item['qty']
              }
              else{
                $quantity_per_product[$_product_id] = $item['qty']
              }  
         }
     }   
}
foreach( $quantity_per_product as $p_id => $qty){
    echo '('. get_the_title($p_id). ')# You bought '.$qty.' Times<br>';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it return an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING) `

Comment: it return the same result as it was before `if(array_key_exists($_product_id, $quantity_per_product))` statement might not working

Comment: is there any other solution?