# How to get total value by array key from array in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to get how many time a product bought by a customer but failed to get total qty or get the result. How can I short by product_id from an array. Please help how can i short them. [Here is full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291635/how-many-times-a-product-have-been-bought-by-customer-in-last-one-year) **I have applied the anser earlier but it still not working the output stay the same as it was earlier**

```
$lifetime_total = array();
foreach($items as $item) {          
$_product_id = $item['product_id'];
$_product_qty = $item['qty'];

if(isset ($_product_id)){
  if(array_key_exists($_product_id, $lifetime_total))
  {
    $lifetime_total[$_product_id] += $_product_qty;
  }
  else{
    $lifetime_total[$_product_id] = $_product_qty;
  }  
 }

}
foreach( $lifetime_total as $key => $qty){
echo '('. get_the_title($key). ')# You bought '.$qty.' Times<br>';
}
```

**The current output is**

```
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 1 Times
(Product 2)# You bought 1 Times
```

**But I need the result should be look like**

```
(Product 2)# You bought 4 Times
(Product 1)# You bought 4 Times
```

**here is the var_dump**

```html
array(1) { [20]=> array(13) { ["name"]=> string(13) "Test Products" ["type"]=> string(9) "line_item" ["item_meta"]=> array(9) { ["_qty"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_tax_class"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["_product_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } ["_variation_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_subtotal"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "500" } ["_line_total"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "500" } ["_line_subtotal_tax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_tax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_tax_data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } ["item_meta_array"]=> array(9) { [177]=> object(stdClass)#458 (2) { ["key"]=> string(4) "_qty" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [178]=> object(stdClass)#457 (2) { ["key"]=> string(10) "_tax_class" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [179]=> object(stdClass)#456 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_product_id" ["value"]=> string(1) "4" } [180]=> object(stdClass)#455 (2) { ["key"]=> string(13) "_variation_id" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [181]=> object(stdClass)#454 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_subtotal" ["value"]=> string(3) "500" } [182]=> object(stdClass)#453 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_line_total" ["value"]=> string(3) "500" } [183]=> object(stdClass)#452 (2) { ["key"]=> string(18) "_line_subtotal_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [184]=> object(stdClass)#451 (2) { ["key"]=> string(9) "_line_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [185]=> object(stdClass)#450 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_tax_data" ["value"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" ["product_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["variation_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_subtotal"]=> string(3) "500" ["line_total"]=> string(3) "500" ["line_subtotal_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_tax_data"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } array(2) { [11]=> array(13) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Warranty Product 1" ["type"]=> string(9) "line_item" ["item_meta"]=> array(9) { ["_qty"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_tax_class"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["_product_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "63" } ["_variation_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_subtotal"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_total"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_subtotal_tax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_tax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_tax_data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } ["item_meta_array"]=> array(9) { [96]=> object(stdClass)#448 (2) { ["key"]=> string(4) "_qty" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [97]=> object(stdClass)#447 (2) { ["key"]=> string(10) "_tax_class" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [98]=> object(stdClass)#446 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_product_id" ["value"]=> string(2) "63" } [99]=> object(stdClass)#445 (2) { ["key"]=> string(13) "_variation_id" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [100]=> object(stdClass)#444 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_subtotal" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [101]=> object(stdClass)#443 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_line_total" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [102]=> object(stdClass)#442 (2) { ["key"]=> string(18) "_line_subtotal_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [103]=> object(stdClass)#441 (2) { ["key"]=> string(9) "_line_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [104]=> object(stdClass)#440 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_tax_data" ["value"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" ["product_id"]=> string(2) "63" ["variation_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_subtotal"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_total"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_subtotal_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_tax_data"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } [12]=> array(13) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Warranty Product 2" ["type"]=> string(9) "line_item" ["item_meta"]=> array(9) { ["_qty"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_tax_class"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["_product_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "18" } ["_variation_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_subtotal"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_total"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_subtotal_tax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_tax"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["_line_tax_data"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } ["item_meta_array"]=> array(9) { [105]=> object(stdClass)#439 (2) { ["key"]=> string(4) "_qty" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" } [106]=> object(stdClass)#438 (2) { ["key"]=> string(10) "_tax_class" ["value"]=> string(0) "" } [107]=> object(stdClass)#437 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_product_id" ["value"]=> string(2) "18" } [108]=> object(stdClass)#436 (2) { ["key"]=> string(13) "_variation_id" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [109]=> object(stdClass)#435 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_subtotal" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [110]=> object(stdClass)#434 (2) { ["key"]=> string(11) "_line_total" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [111]=> object(stdClass)#433 (2) { ["key"]=> string(18) "_line_subtotal_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [112]=> object(stdClass)#432 (2) { ["key"]=> string(9) "_line_tax" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" } [113]=> object(stdClass)#431 (2) { ["key"]=> string(14) "_line_tax_data" ["value"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } } ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" ["tax_class"]=> string(0) "" ["product_id"]=> string(2) "18" ["variation_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_subtotal"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_total"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_subtotal_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_tax"]=> string(1) "0" ["line_tax_data"]=> string(45) "a:2:{s:5:"total";a:0:{}s:8:"subtotal";a:0:{}}" } }
```

Comment: I can add here the screenshot this is the output i'm not sure why . [here is full code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291635/how-many-times-a-product-have-been-bought-by-customer-in-last-one-year)

Comment: I have checked the answer given earlier but not worked

Comment: I have added the dump in question section

Answer (score 0):

`$_product_qty` seems to be an array of strings

Try to change the code to:

```
$lifetime_total = array();
foreach($items as $item) {          
$_product_id = $item['product_id'];
$_product_qty_array = $item['qty']; 
$_product_qty = 0;

if(count($_product_qty_array) > 0){

    $_product_qty = intval($_product_qty_array[0]);
} 

if(isset ($_product_id)){
  if(array_key_exists($_product_id, $lifetime_total))
  {
     $lifetime_total[$_product_id] += $_product_qty;
  }
  else{
  $lifetime_total[$_product_id] = $_product_qty;
  }  
 }
}

foreach( $lifetime_total as $key => $qty){
 echo '('. get_the_title($key). ')# You bought '.$qty.' Times<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this also not works . still the answer remain same.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might help:

```
$data = array( ... ); // your beginning array

$result = array(); // the end array

foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {

    if ( !isset( $result[ $key ] ) ) {

        $result[ $key ] = $value;

    } else {

        $result[ $key ] += $value;

    }

}
```